# How to add a button or link to perform an action on a node with node_view?

Tags: 7, entities

I wonder how to add a button or link to perform an action of _create_node function. I understand on how to do it on the node edit screen, but not the display.

I want a button of create "new item" on the node display. I'm creating a custom module to create the new node, but need a button to call it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your requirement is to add button in node display..??

Comment: Yeah that is what i'm trying to do. I want a button of create "new item" on the node display. I'm creating a custom module to create the new node, but need a button to call it. Not sure where to go from here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement the `hook_node_view()` like the following code:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'CONTENT_TYPE_NAME') {
    $form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form');
    $node->content['redirect_button'] = $form;
 }
}

function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('New Item'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    //here the path where you need to go
    $path = 'node/add/CONTENT_TYPE_NAME';
    drupal_goto($path);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my question, thank you.

Comment: @ThroneDigital a pleasure, and god luck in your projects

Answer (score 2):

For adding any custom link/button on node display, try by adding your code in **tpl file**. For customizing node display add your code in `node.tpl.php`.

For tpl naming conventions and more details, Please refer

1. [Theming nodes by content type.](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565)
2. [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

Hope this will help you.